# Replacing values in a data frame with NULL

Tags: r

Can you replace using NULL?

```
#Data Frame
a = c("tom", "alex", "chris", "jen", "mary") 
b = c(NA) 
df = data.frame(a,b) 

#Replace Tom with NULL
df$c <- gsub('tom', NULL, df$a)
```

The last line of code gives me the following error: `invalid 'replacement' argument`.  Is replacement with NULL possible?  Reason I ask, is cause I'm trying to upload a large dataset into postgres and some integer variables are being rejected due to having blanks and NA values.  Thanks.

Comment: You cannot use NULL. See `c(1, 2, NULL)`. Notice that NULL is removed. `df$c` is the same beast.

Comment: How are you loading the data into postgres? That may well be a path to a solution.

Comment: I'm loading the data into postgres via rails that is in a csv format.  Postgres rejects integer variables with observations that are blank(i.e., "") or NA.  It won't reject NULL values, so I'm trying to replace NAs and blanks in my data frame with NULL.  Do you think that this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you are asking. But here are some example that might help

```
#this replaces tom with NA 
df$c = gsub('tom', NA, df$a)
```

[NULL vs NA](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-na-vs-null/)

```
#this creates a vector of two elements, as NULL is nothing   
d = c("a","b",NULL)

#this creates a vector with three elements, as NA is blank
e = c("a","b",NA)
```

Remove all elements with "tom"

```
e = df$a[df$a != "tom"]
```

Comment: I think a better way to ask this questions is, can R hold a NULL value?  Can I replace values in vector with NULL and I believe I just learned that it cannot, based on this discussion.  https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-na-vs-null/